# Como refrescar el token en sanctum laravel

Tags: laravel-8

Estoy usando Sanctum Tokens para la autenticacion, ya tengo toda esa parte desarrollada y funcionando, pero tengo un problemita.

Como manejan los tokens caducados, el refrescar el token en sanctum, he programado una solucion la cual funciona y me refresca el token, pero lo hace siempre y cuando la ruta de la api sea publica, si la pongo en una ruta protegida ahi ya no me funciona por que el token ya caduco.

[image: axios]

[image: rutas laravel]

Comment: En vez de poner fotos del codigo, copia y pega el codigo para que podamos intentar replicar el codigo sin que nos lleve mucho tiempo...

Answer (score 1):

¡Hola! La solución a esto es 'relativamente' sencilla. En lugar de crear un método para refrescar el Token, lo que deberías hacer es lo siguiente:

Cuando haces la petición de Login desde el front, guarda en el campo `remember_token` de tu tabla de usuarios de la base de datos el token generado.

Guarda también un localStorage desde tu front con el token generado. O bien, una Cookie con caducidad. Al hacer logout simplemente limpia el token del localStorage o la Cookie. Con esto podrás filtrar desde tu back siempre que quieras y necesites!

PD: Nunca he usado Sactum, pero es una manera sencilla de desarrollarlo en JWT.

Te dejo un pequeño ejemplo de esto:

***Front:***

Almacenar el token:

```
localStorage.setItem('token', response.token);
```

Acceder al token:

```
localStorage.getItem('token');
```

Back:

Actualizar el token:

```
public function login(Request $request) {
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
    try {
        if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 400);
        }
    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
    }

    $user = User::where('email', $request->get('email'))->first();
    $user->remember_token = $token;
    $user->update();

    return response()->json(compact('token'), 201);
}
```

Obtener usuario por el token:

```
$token = $request->header('Authorization');

$user = User::where('remember_token', $token)->first();
```

Puedes basarte en este ejemplo para solucionar tu problema.